# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.getpageSource returns html document without quotes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to retrieve HTML source of a webpage using the `Selenium class WebDriver`. But the function `getPageSource()` returns the HTML document without quotes for any of the attributes.
Because of this the DOM parser throws `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:Open quote is expected for attribute` exception.

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use it for this purpose. From the [API doc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource%28%29):

> java.lang.String getPageSource()
>
> Get the source of the last loaded page. If the page has been modified
>   after loading (for example, by Javascript) there is no guarantee that
>   the returned text is that of the modified page. Please consult the
>   documentation of the particular driver being used to determine whether
>   the returned text reflects the current state of the page or the text
>   last sent by the web server. The page source returned is a
>   representation of the underlying DOM: do not expect it to be formatted
>   or escaped in the same way as the response sent from the web server.
>   Think of it as an artist's impression.

Anyway, I suggest trying another browser if you really need to use WebDriver for this and your current browser is not working a expected. I just tried with FireFoxDriver (driver v2.40) and I had my quotes there.

Comment: But I need to execute the test case in IE only. No other borwser allowed